# Symfony createView causes error

Tags: forms, symfony

I am using Symfony 3.3.10

I have the following code

```
 /**
     * @Route("/meta/edit/{metaId}", name="edit_price_meta_data")
     */
    public function editMetaAction(Request $request,ItemPriceMeta $metaId)
    {
        $metaDataForm = $this->createForm("ItemBundle\Form\ItemPriceMetaType");

        $data = [
            'metaData'=>$metaId,
            'metaDataForm'=>$metaDataForm->createView(),
        ];
        return $this->render("@Item/Prices/Manage/editMetaData.html.twig",$data);
    }
```

It produces the following error.

```
Error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

in vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php (line 2513)

public function createEntity($className, array $data, &$hints = array()){
        $class = $this->em->getClassMetadata($className);
        //$isReadOnly = isset($hints[Query::HINT_READ_ONLY])

        $id = $this->identifierFlattener->flattenIdentifier($class, $data); 

        $idHash = implode(' ', $id);
        if (isset($this->identityMap[$class->rootEntityName][$idHash])) {            
            $entity = $this->identityMap[$class->rootEntityName][$idHash];            
            $oid = spl_object_hash($entity);
```

The actual line highlighted as causing the error is `$id = $this->identifierFlattener->flattenIdentifier($class, $data);`

Removing `'metaDataForm'=>$metaDataForm->createView(),` from my array, removes the error, so it seems to be the rendering of the form that is causing the error.

Comment: Normally I would suggest posting the code for ItemPriceMetaType but I suspect it is a monster class.  Plus I suspect the error has nothing to do with it but is rather coming from some other code.  So good luck.

Comment: @PrestonDocker, just wondering, every found the solution? I got the exact same thing at the moment locally. php used to handle this page just fine, but somehow it started to cause an execution timed out.

Answer (score 0):

Increase PHP memory usage in php.ini

Comment: Thanks for your time looking at this, but that is not my problem, I don't have many records in my test data. This query should only take a fraction of a second. I need to find the cause of the problem.